# Filter df using numpy/pandas with multiple conditions, tres date and one object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-datetime

my name is Victor, i have aspergers syndrome
I can't understand functions clearly enough to synthesize them in my mind and communicate them to the computer, but i can visualize and express in visual situations

I have a dataframe populated with registration of memberships, cancellations and unaffiliations over the years.

I need to know who the affiliates were on a given date.

The user may have ceased to be a member for 2 reasons, cancellation or disaffiliation, sometimes both.

*I'll show you with 2 different out examples of what I need the computer to do with the dataframe*

### **Database sample:**

```py
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.DataFrame({'political party': ['MDB', 'MDB', 'PODE', 'PDT', 'PSL',  'PV', 'PSL', 'PT', 'PL'], 
                   'affiliated': ['Bob', 'John', 'Olivia', 'James', 'Victor', 'Victor', 'Emma', 'Rose', 'Mark'],
                   'date_affiliation': ['2006-01-31', '2011-04-11', '2007-09-04', '2009-10-13', '2017-12-30', '2020-09-02', '1992-02-23', '2010-10-19', '1985-06-22'],
                   'situation': ['unaffiliated', 'affiliated',  'canceled', 'canceled', 'canceled', 'affiliated', 'affiliated', 'unaffiliated', 'canceled'],
                   'date_disaffiliation': ['2020-02-18', '', '', '2011-11-23', '', '', '', '2010-10-30', '2010-04-08'],
                   'date_cancellation': ['', '', '2019-10-15', '2011-11-10', '2020-07-02', '', '', '', '2010-04-08']})

cols_date = ['date_affiliation', 'date_disaffiliation', 'date_cancellation']
for col in cols_date:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MDB | Bob | 2006-01-31 | unaffiliated | 2020-02-18 | NaT |
| 1 | MDB | John | 2011-04-11 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 2 | PODE | Olivia | 2007-09-04 | canceled | NaT | 2019-10-15 |
| 3 | PDT | James | 2009-10-13 | canceled | 2011-11-23 | 2011-11-10 |
| 4 | PSL | Victor | 2017-12-30 | canceled | NaT | 2020-07-02 |
| 5 | PV | Victor | 2020-09-02 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 6 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 7 | PT | Rose | 2010-10-19 | unaffiliated | 2010-10-30 | NaT |
| 8 | PL | Mark | 1985-06-22 | canceled | 2010-04-08 | 2010-04-08 |

### Out sample One

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation | affiliat_2005_08_15 | affiliat_2010_08_07 | affiliat_2020_01_05 | affiliat_2020_11_15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MDB | Bob | 2006-01-31 | unaffiliated | 2020-02-18 | NaT | False | True | True | False |
| 1 | MDB | John | 2011-04-11 | affiliated | NaT | NaT | False | False | True | True |
| 2 | PODE | Olivia | 2007-09-04 | canceled | NaT | 2019-10-15 | False | True | False | False |
| 3 | PDT | James | 2009-10-13 | canceled | 2011-11-23 | 2011-11-10 | False | True | False | False |
| 4 | PSL | Victor | 2017-12-30 | canceled | NaT | 2020-07-02 | False | False | True | False |
| 5 | PV | Victor | 2020-09-02 | affiliated | NaT | NaT | False | False | False | True |
| 6 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT | True | True | True | True |
| 7 | PT | Rose | 2010-10-19 | unaffiliated | 2010-10-30 | NaT | False | False | False | False |
| 8 | PL | Mark | 1985-06-22 | canceled | 2010-04-08 | 2010-04-08 | True | False | False | False |

### Out sample Two

**affiliates in 2005_08_15**

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 1 | PL | Mark | 1985-06-22 | canceled | 2010-04-08 | 2010-04-08 |

**affiliates in 2010_08_07**

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MDB | Bob | 2006-01-31 | unaffiliated | 2020-02-18 | NaT |
| 1 | PODE | Olivia | 2007-09-04 | canceled | NaT | 2019-10-15 |
| 2 | PDT | James | 2009-10-13 | canceled | 2011-11-23 | 2011-11-10 |
| 3 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |

**affiliates in 2020_01_05**

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MDB | Bob | 2006-01-31 | unaffiliated | 2020-02-18 | NaT |
| 1 | MDB | John | 2011-04-11 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 2 | PSL | Victor | 2017-12-30 | canceled | NaT | 2020-07-02 |
| 3 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |

**affiliates in df_2020_11_15**

|  | political party | affiliated | date_affiliation | situation | date_disaffiliation | date_cancellation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MDB | John | 2011-04-11 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 1 | PV | Victor | 2020-09-02 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |
| 2 | PSL | Emma | 1992-02-23 | affiliated | NaT | NaT |

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] before posting.

Comment: Ow Sorry, this is my first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help you in the right direction?

```
# date to test:
date = '2010-08-07'

# Caluclate some help columns:
affiliated_before_date = df.date_affiliation <= date
disaffiliation_before_date =  df.date_disaffiliation <= date
cancellation_before_date =  df.date_cancellation <= date

# Final logic. Must be affiliated, but then NOT disaffiliated or cancelled.
people_to_include = affiliated_before_date & ~( disaffiliation_before_date | cancellation_before_date)

df[people_to_include]
```

[image]

For the second output asked for I would do something like:

```
dates_to_add = ['2005-08-15','2010-08-07','2020-01-05','2020-11-15']

def calculate_new_data_column(df, date):
    
    affiliated_before_date = df.date_affiliation <= date
    disaffiliation_before_date =  df.date_disaffiliation <= date
    cancellation_before_date =  df.date_cancellation <= date
    
    return affiliated_before_date & ~( disaffiliation_before_date | cancellation_before_date)

for date in dates_to_add:
    df[f'affiliat-{date}'] = calculate_new_data_column(df, date)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much. do you have the possibility to create a new boolean column, in the dataframe [people_to_include 2010-08-07], using your script?

Comment: Added some example output for the second output type. If this helped please upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

> .where()

method like that:

```
df.where(df['date_affiliation'] <= '2005-08-15')
```

You can use :

> [ '<' , '>'  , '=='  ,   '>=' ]

instead  " <= " , To find the data you want.

Comment: I asked the computer to do this for me, beyond the year 2005, like in 2020 or 2022. But it showed me all the results and not just the affiliates of a specific date. 

I think I need to show that an affiliate may not be affiliated for 2 reasons, date_disaffiliatio and date_cancellation

Comment: I designed another way to show you, called it **Out sample One**, it lives in the new issue of the question.